# SQL average for fields with 0

Tags: php, sql

I have a SQL queries with the some ratings like

```
location, cleanliness, money, kitchen, checkinprocess, servicebyowner
```

For few data `checkinprocess`, `servicebyowner` are `0`. I just want to calculate the average of the values.

I want to cheeck in my query like,if there are 20 rows as result, average of `checkinprocess`, `serviceby owner` must be calculated only for existing rows (if it is only for 2 rows out of 10 rows result)it must calculate average only for 2 rows, but for other rows it can be calculated based upn the number of rows. Here is the query which i have written:

```
  select count(customdata) as CNT,
         customdata,
         sum(service_by_owner) as ser,
         sum(checkinprocess) as chk,
         sum(locationrating) as loc,
         sum(cleanlinessrating) as cle,
         sum(valueformoneyrating) as val,
         sum(kitchenequipmentrating) as kit
    from feedback
group by customdata HAVING customdata !='null' AND customdata!='';
```

I am able to calculate the average for rest of the four
   field based upon the rows,but for this two fields is bit tricky for
   me.

**Edit:**

PHP used to calculate the average:

```
foreach($result as $row){
  $arrValues[] = array("customdata"=>$row['customdata'],
                       "checkinprocess"=>ceil(($row['chk'])),
                       "service_by_owner"=>(ceil($row['ser'])),
                       "valueformoneyrating"=>ceil(($row['val']/($row['CNT']*4))*100), 
                       "locationrating"=>ceil(($row['loc']/($row['CNT']*4))*100),
                       "kitchenequipmentrating"=>ceil(($row['kit']/($row['CNT']*4))*100), 
                       "cleanlinessrating"=>ceil(($row['cle']/($row['CNT']*4))*100));
}
```

This checkinprocess and servicebyowner, I must calculate average only for the existing rows not for all which is 0.

Comment: Your query only sums up the columns. There is no average calculated. What did you try to solve your problem?

Comment: I'm trying to find average in PHP

Comment: I've already added your code. It's not necessary to add it twice.

Comment: Why are you storing 0 ratings if you don't want them in the calculations? Values with no information shopuld preoperly be stored as null. Zero values should have meaning  and thus be part of the average.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of speculation . . . but you seem to want the average of the values that are not 0.  You can do this by using the SQL avg function:

```
select count(customdata) as CNT,
       customdata,
       avg(case when service_by_owner <> 0 then service_by_owner*1.0 end)*4*100.0 as ser,
       avg(case when checkinprocess<> 0 then checkinprocess*1.0 end)*4*100.0  as chk,
       avg(case when locationrating<> 0 then locationrating*1.0 end)*4*100.0  as loc,
       avg(case when cleanlinessrating<> 0 then cleanlinessrating*1.0 end)*4*100.0  as cle,
       avg(case when valueformoneyrating<> 0 then valueformoneyrating*1.0 end)*4*100.0  as val,
       avg(case when kitchenequipmentrating<> 0 then kitchenequipmentrating*1.0 end)*4*100.0  as kit
from feedback
WHERE customdata <> 'null' AND customdata <> ''; 
group by customdata
```

[The multiplication by 4*100 is based on the comments.]

You don't mention which SQL engine you are using, so I converted all the values to floats (by multiplying by 1.0), so the average is always a float.  This is not necessary in all databases.

I also changed the `HAVING` clause to a `WHERE` clause.  This is somewhat a matter of preference, but I think of this as filtering the input rather than the output.  Also, do you mean `customdata <> 'null'` or `customdata is not null`?

Comment: Hi,thank u but I want to claculate my average based upon the number of rows return count(customdata) as CNT so,[sum(locationrating)/CNT *4]*100..

Comment: @Indira Why did you accept this answer if it doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: @Indira . . . You can take the average calcualted in SQL and multiply by 4*100.0.